# Inserting NULL into geography type using OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I run this query

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
tt Geography
)

INSERT INTO t(tt)
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([Server2],'SELECT NULL')
```

it throws an error

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 14 Operand type clash: int is
>   incompatible with geography

But When I run this, it works fine:

```
INSERT INTO t(tt)
SELECT NULL
```

I need to use `OPENQUERY`, how I can fix above problem? Ideally, I need a fix within `OPENQUERY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is actually telling you the problem here, `NULL` has a value type of `int`. This reason for this is because you haven't defined a type for your column, so the default is `int` and that data type is returned from `OPENQUERY`. You can see this by running the below:

```
SELECT system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT NULL;',NULL,0);
```

Notice value returned is `int`. You need to hard convert your value:

```
INSERT INTO t(tt)
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([Server2],'SELECT CONVERT(geography,NULL)');
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know NULL has any data type

Comment: The problem is that a result set is being returned from `OPENQUERY` @EricKlaus. A column *has* to have a data type, and as that hasn't been defined SQL Server has had to *infer* one; as a result it uses `int`.